# Replace selected value from data validation list with another value

Tags: excel, validation

I have two tables in different sheets. The first one has two columns (Name and Abbreviated Name) and the second one has many columns one of them has data validation list for its cells based on the first column (Name) in the first table. What I want to do is: when I select a value from the drop down list I want it to be replaced with the corresponding value in the (abbreviated Name) column, how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This will not do exactly what you ask, but should help you with the purpose, unless that is different from what I  can guess.

Create a second column to the right of you column with drop down lists, and make and index/match lookup on you Name and Abbreviated Name table like this:
Assuming you have the dropdown lists in col A from row 2 and down it will be entered in B2 and downwards.

```
=INDEX(Abbreviated Name;MATCH(A2;Name;0))
```

Change my ; to , if you language uses , as formula separator.
This will result in that you many-columned sheet has an additional row, one for showing abbrebiated name and one for selecting the real name. You could probably do exactly what you want using VBA, if you have at least 1 empty cell in your Name list that you use to create the data validation (allowing you to select values not in the list, but this will make it more complex than it needs to be.